# Error printing on python stating cannot concenate string to list

Tags: python, string, list, api

Receiving the following error stating Error:

```
can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

```py
import urllib.request
zipcode = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]
for zipcodes in zipcode:
    link = "url"+zipcode
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = f.read()
    print (str(data, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: you need to use `zipcodes` like link = "url"+zipcode`s`

Answer (score 0):

You are being tripped up by your naming conventions.  Specifically, you are mixing up `zipcode` and `zipcodes` in your for loop.  Here is your code:

```
...

zipcode = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]

for zipcodes in zipcode:
    link = "url"+zipcode
...
```

`zipcode` is your list, and `zipcodes` is an element in that list, so when you try to concatenate "url" to `zipcode` (your list) you get the error you are seeing. So,  you need to switch them around.  Alternatively, you could use more descriptive names to help avoid mistakes like that in the future:

```
...

zipcode_list = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]

for one_zipcode in zipcode_list:
    link = "url" + one_zipcode
...
```

Comment: I modified it and am now getting an error of 401: import urllib.request

zipcode_list = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]
for one_zipcode in zipcode_list:
    link = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=72714&appid=e7c3fb6e681c8f7bb59af33f1dc8bbca"+one_zipcode
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = f.read()
    print (str(data, 'utf-8'))

Comment: Oops I figured it out. had the zipcode in wrong section. My bad. Thank you!

Comment: So, question, how to I make it look like "Morrilton : 269.03" when it prints out? Right now it's printing the temp out below the city.

Answer (score 0):

After the problem of line four is solved, line five of this

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
unknown url type: 'url 7160' gives error
```

-------Code:

```
import urllib.request
zipcode = ["7160","72454","71834","72223","72110"]
for zipcodes in zipcode:
    link = "url"+zipcodes
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    data = f.read()
    print (str(data, 'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate url to list effectively. I suggest you

1. Rename your zipcode list to **zipcodes**
2. In your for statement, do

```python
for zipcodes in zipcode:
        link = "url"+zipcode   # the zipcode variable is a string value
        ....
```

Exception will occure after beacause "url" is not a correct url. URL must be like : "http://example.com", that is a well formated url